# Django create superuser issue fail to log in admin page

Tags: python, django, admin

While trying to create a superuser in Django project this message always shows up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name setup_environ
```

although the superuser is created and it saved in the database but I can't log into the admin page and gives me error message that the credentials are wrong (I'm using the built-in admin interface).

I tried looking up the problem but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Maybe you could proveide some more informations ? Do you create superuser during syncdb ? Or by other manage.py command ? How did you check that user has been created ?

Comment: While trying to create the superuser during syncdb it says "Skip superuser creation when not running in a TTY" so I created the superuser manually manage.py createsuperuser. The user is created because I checked the database data and it's there in the auth_user.

Comment: Any thought what the problem might be?

Comment: Do you use pycharm with Django 1.7? If yes, `createuser` does not work in their terminal and you should open a terminal by your own.